# Add nested properties to the existing class at runtime and export it to json as per below format

Tags: c#

I need to fetch all the table names and their column names from database using an sql query in c# console application and export it to json. The problem is that i don't know what the table names and column names at compile time and i need to add them to the class as property on runtime. The json format should be below:-
For example:
Database name is mydatabase
Tables names are tbl1,tbl2,tbl3
Column names are tbl1(tbl1Col1, tbl1col2), tbl2(tbl2Col1, tbl2col2),tbl3(tbl3Col1, tbl3col2)

Json format should be:

```
{
  "tables":{
      "tbl1":{
            "columns": {
                  "tbl1Col1":{},
                  "tbl1Col2":{},
            }    
  },
      "tbl2":{
              "columns": {
                  "tbl2Col1":{},
                  "tbl2Col2":{},
            }
  },
      "tbl3":{
             "columns": {
                  "tbl3Col1":{},
                  "tbl3Col2":{},
            }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Speaking intuitively, whenever I see a property that's a plural, in this case `tables`, I'd expect it to be a collection of some sort, is there a concrete reason for `tables` not to be an array?

Comment: As you can see there is no square bracket in the json format which i have provided, which means no collection should be used. this is the json format which is expected for furthur processing.

Comment: Yup, I can see that, which is why I asked. But is there any inherent reason not to use an array? Do you already have customers that are relying on this structure? Or is this a self imposed limitation you could lift to make your (and your consumers) lives easier?

Comment: its already been used by several customers can't change it now. i need to adhere to this structure only. could you please provide me solution if you have any?

Answer (score 1):

I do have a solution, I was just too tired (caffeine depraved) to notice it, just use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0), so

```cs
class Root // Whatever your class is called
{
    [JsonPropertyName("tables")]
    public Dictionary<string, Table> Tables { get; set; } = new();
}

class Table
{
    [JsonPropertyName("columns")]
    public Dictionary<string, Column> Columns { get; set; } = new();
}

class Column { }
```

You can then just `JsonSerializer,Serialize(root)` and it works and produces JSON in the correct structure you want. I created a small demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdlrcB) to showcase it (don't be alarmed, you can construct your dictionaries however you want, I just used a lot of syntactic sugar)

Comment: You are a champ :) its working as expected. thanks a lot for your help MindSwipe.

Comment: No problem, here to help. And I hate asking this, but could accept the answer? It's not that I want or need the rep, just for potential future readers to see (and to fight the statistical rise of questions without an accepted answer)

Comment: already accepted it. thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work with nested ExpandoObjects.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        dynamic rootTables = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic tables = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic tbl1Col1 = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic columns = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic column = new ExpandoObject();


        AddProperty(column, "tbl1Col1", tbl1Col1);
        AddProperty(columns, "columns", column);
        AddProperty(tables, "tbl1",  columns);
        AddProperty(rootTables, "tables", tables);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootTables);

        Assert.AreEqual("{\"tables\":{\"tbl1\":{\"columns\":{\"tbl1Col1\":{}}}}}", json);
    }


    public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;
        if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
        else
            expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }
```

Comment: You're treating the `ExpanoObject`s as dictionaries, so why not just use dictionaries all the way down and keep at least a semblance of type guarantees?